# Moose (Perl): convert undef to empty string or 0 rather than die()

Tags: perl, undefined, moose

I've received **a lot of exceptions** from QA due to incomplete data being fed to my Moose constructors. The attribute name is present in the constructor arguments, but the value is `undef`.

It's a fact of life with many scripting applications that things are just `undef`. And oftentimes this is perfectly fine. You don't want an annoying warning from the `warnings` pragma (so you do `no warnings 'uninitialized'`), and you certainly don't want your code to die because one little value, say the housenumber, is `undef`.

So without further ado, I want my Moose constructors to behave like straight Perl (i.e. without `use warnings 'uninitialized'`), which is to convert `undef` to `0` or the empty string as required. The attempt shown in this sample does not work for the case where the attribute name is present but the value is `undef`. I could think of using `BUILDARGS` to achieve what I want. But is there a declarative way in plain Moose without [resorting to MooseX::UndefTolerant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5823685/269126) (which unfortunately I cannot use as it is not installed)?

```
package AAA;
use Moose;
has 'hu', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str';
has 'ba', is => 'ro', isa => 'Int';
no Moose; __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package BBB;
use Moose; extends 'AAA';
has '+hu', default => ''; # don't want to die on undef
has '+ba', default => 0;  # idem
no Moose; __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
# Those AAAs should die ...
throws_ok { AAA->new( hu => undef ) }
    qr/Validation failed for 'Str' with value undef/;
throws_ok { AAA->new( ba => undef ) }
    qr/Validation failed for 'Int' with value undef/;
# .. but these BBBs should live:
lives_ok  { BBB->new( hu => undef ) } 'hu supplied as undef';
lives_ok  { BBB->new( ba => undef ) } 'ba supplied as undef';
done_testing;
```

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't be trying to suppress warnings. Why don't you check if values are defined before hand? `(defined($value))` Also, you could install `MooseX::UndefTolerant` locally to some directory `$my_dir` and `use lib($my_dir);`

Comment: The problem is type constraints. When you say foo isa Int, and you supply an undef for foo, it fails the type constraint because undef isn't an Int.

Comment: @YGomez +1 Nice idea, I might in fact be doing this. :-) As for warnings because of uninitialized values, see [`common::sense`](http://p3rl.org/common::sense). I agree with the author Marc Lehmann in his discussion of uninitialized values. (There are exceptions, but hey - they're exceptions.) Checking the values beforehand is just cumbersome. I'd have to repeat the checks in many places and I try to stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: common::sense is no common sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [Moose::Manual::Types](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod) is a way documented to deal with exactly this kind of problem.

Use the `Maybe[a]` type.

```
package AAA;
use Moose;

has 'hu', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str';
has 'ba', is => 'ro', isa => 'Int';

no Moose; __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;


package BBB;
use Moose; extends 'AAA';

has 'hu', is => 'rw', isa => 'Maybe[Str]', default => ''; # will not die on undef
has 'ba', is => 'rw', isa => 'Maybe[Int]', default => 0;  # idem

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->hu('') unless defined $self->hu;
    $self->ba(0) unless defined $self->ba;
}

no Moose; __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;


package main;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;

# Those AAAs should die ...
throws_ok { AAA->new( hu => undef ) }
    qr/Validation failed for 'Str' with value undef/;
throws_ok { AAA->new( ba => undef ) }
    qr/Validation failed for 'Int' with value undef/;

# .. but these BBBs should live:
lives_ok  { BBB->new( hu => undef ) } 'hu supplied as undef';
lives_ok  { BBB->new( ba => undef ) } 'ba supplied as undef';

my $bbb = BBB->new( hu => undef, ba => undef );

is $bbb->hu, '', "hu is ''";
is $bbb->ba, 0, 'ba is 0';

done_testing;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The `undef` values don't get autoconverted to `0` and the empty string, respectively, but I guess I'll have to put with up that. (Or write my own `MooseX::UndefUpgrade` extension.)

Comment: To set a value when undef is passed you could use the BUILD sub that gets invoked on object creation via `BBB->new`. Updated code accordingly. You would have to set the attributes `'rw'` though.

Comment: Now I don't know how Moose sorts things out internally (I know, open source ...), but I might not be alone in thinking that it would stand to benefit from endowing the attribute declarator (`has`) with an `onundef` property. Looks like you could say that the default behaviour of `onundef` is to `croak` (or `confess`). But why not `has 'something', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', onundef => ''`? [`Class::MOP::Attribute`](http://p3rl.org/Class::MOP::Attribute) has `default` and `initializer`, but neither is suitable for the special case of handling `undef`.

Comment: I disagree on this one. I think the API should be kept as narrow as possible. The type system contains Undef and it can be validated and handled like the other types can. If an attribute is not set during construction the default value/callback will jump in. If it is set it will not. That is consistant behaviour and should not be changed for one type or the other. If you need to mangle the data passed in you can still use BUILD.

Answer (score 4):

Your complaint really is that Moose is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.  If you explicitly pass `undef` as a value, but that value can only be an `Int`, then you *should* get an error.

So you need to make a choice.  You can either change the type (via union) to allow `undef` as a valid value like so:

```
    has 'hu', is => 'ro', isa => 'Str | Undef';
    has 'ba', is => 'ro', isa => 'Int | Undef';
```

Or you can just not send in undefined values:

```
    my %aa_params = ();
    $aa_params{hu} = $foo if defined $foo;

    $aa = AA->new( %aa_params );
```

Or finally, for some unknown reason you absolutely cannot resist sending in invalid undefined values for things which should not be explicitly set to undefined, just write a quick filter:

```
    sub filt_undef {
      my %hash = @_;
      return map { $_ => $hash{$_} } grep { defined $hash{$_} } keys %hash;
    }

    $aa = AA->new( filt_undef( hu => undef ) );
```

But this seems rather awkward and awful.

Comment: Your suggestion using a union works fine, too. The `Maybe` solution is a more idiomatic expression for the `undef` problem and hence to be preferred for this problem, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Or use on-the-fly coercion:

```
package BBB;
use Moose;
use MooseX::AttributeShortcuts;
extends 'AAA';
has '+hu',
  traits => [Shortcuts],
  coerce => [ Undef => sub { '' } ],
;
```